# ngInit not interpreting expression as true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that builds a file tree. As part of that, I'm trying to check a checkbox by default using ngModel and ngInit, but I'm not getting the behavior I expect. This code is from the linking function:

**Javascript**

```
var treeSelectAll = true
```

**HTML** (not working)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="node.selected" ng-init="node.selected = treeSelectAll">
```

**HTML** (working)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="node.selected" ng-init="node.selected = true">
```

Why is ngInit not evaluating `treeSelectAll` as `true`?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try:

```
$scope.treeSelectAll = true
```

instead

```
var treeSelectAll = true
```

Comment: This code is actually in a directive linking function, HTML and all. Scope isn't the issue.